# Space separator INSTEAD of a comma - large number outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

You'll see in my `form` tag, I'm using `toLocaleString` to to put a separator in my final output. However I want a space instead of a comma. How can I achieve that?

Right now, the third output has a comma in it. But ideally I want all three outputs to have a space in it to make large numbers more readable.

Example: "5 000", "400 000" etc.

```html
<form 
  oninput="loanval.value=loan.value; 
           periodval.value=period.value; 
           paymentval.value=Math.floor(loan.value / period.value).toLocaleString()">
  <label>Loan Amount</label>
  <input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="400000" step="5000">
  <output name="loanval" for="loan">0</output>
  <label>Loan Period</label>
  <input type="range" id="period" name="period" min="1" max="15">
  <output name="periodval" for="period">0</output>
  <label>Your monthly repayment will be:</label>
  <output name="paymentval">0</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point of the `.toLocaleString()` function is that it chooses the correct thousands and decimal separators based on the locale (and lakh separators, etc), so there's no option to just explicitly say "I would like to use a space for this separator, please."

If you're absolutely certain your site will only be running in locales that use a period as the decimal separator you could just do `.toLocaleString('en-US').replace(',', ' ')`

That is, force it to use `en-US` which uses commas for thousands and periods for decimals, and then just manually replace the commas. It's not very elegant, but then I'd argue the whole idea of removing a locale's standard/recognizable thousands separator to make numbers "more readable" is itself not very elegant.

Comment: Thanx so much for the detailed info. Was very helpful :)

Comment: I don't think you'd want to use `.replace(',', ' ')` as that would only find the first instance. You could use the new `.replaceAll(',', ' ')` or regex to replace all instances

Comment: For at least some countries in western europe (I can't speak for everywhere), the "official" thousands separator is considered archaic and inappropriate for the web. So at least in some cases, it is quite necessary to do such a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)
correctly you can force spaces - the French use spaces

```js
num = 5000;

console.log(num.toLocaleString('fr'));

num = 400000;

console.log(num.toLocaleString('fr'));

num = 1234.50; // decimals need more information

console.log(num.toLocaleString('fr', {
  'minimumFractionDigits': 2,
  'maximumFractionDigits': 2
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a JS script that can do this job, Give it a try:

```js
function addspace(num, separator) {
    var mainString = num.toString();
    mainString = mainString.split("").reverse().join("");

    mainString = mainString.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(separator);
    mainString = mainString.split("").reverse().join("");

    return mainString;
}

console.log(addspace(1000, " "));

console.log(addspace(10000, " "));
```